# Control telephone functionality via application (i.e. .NET using TAPI)?

Tags: .net, telephony, tapi, pbx

A colleague recently asked me is it possible without the use of a big PBX system or having to use more involved Asterisk technology to..

.. find a telephone that simply plugs into the phone socket, can be used for normal telephone functionality, but can also be connected to a PC/laptop that sits beside the phone, and once turned on, can utilise TAPI or similar to connect to the phone and using maybe a .NET app/TAPI, pick up calls, make calls etc on the line coming from the phone?

I wondered if any one on here knows if this is possible?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I know you can get a phone that will run both connections quiet easily. As for running TAPI without a PBX, I am not sure. I think Windows does have it's own TAPI solution.